# Python: deleting a string object in a list based on the length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to delete each city from the list if the number of the characters is 5 or less.

```
cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai"]
j = 0
for i in cities:
    if len(i) <= 5:
        del cities[j]
    j += 1
```

That deletes only the first city which is 5 characters or less. But not the second one.

I also tried this:

```
i = 0
while i < len(cities):
    if len(cities[i]) <= 5:
        del cities[i]
    i += 1
```

but it gave me the same result!!

**UPDATE:**
The easiest way to do it is just to add a slice:

```
for i in cities[:]:
        if len(i) <= 5:
            cities.remove(i)       

# output: ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich"]
```

Comment: You're changing the list while iterating over it and that'll cause problem.

Comment: Thanks @Kasramvd but how to do it then ? any better ways?

Comment: You should use a list comprehension: `[i for i in cities if len(i) >= 5]`

Comment: Thank you @Kasramvd  appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is known as a [Filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) operation. You should look at the docs. The following code uses it to generate a brand new list of city names in a single line of code. Constructing a new list will prevent you from a whole class of mistakes that you can make while mutating your memory. The wiki article on [Referential Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency) is a good starting point.

```
cities = ["New York", "Shanghai", "Munich", "Toyko", "Dubai"]

citiesWithLongNames = filter (lambda cityName: len (cityName) > 5, cities)

print (citiesWithLongNames) # => ['New York', 'Shanghai', 'Munich']
```

---

You should also read up on all the [built in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html), and you'll find that there is a bunch of stuff built into python already that keeps you from having to implement trivialities manually.

---

**Bonus: Using List Comprehensions:**

```
print ([city for city in cities if len (city) > 5])
```

Much cleaner than nested loops. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! Since I'm new I couldn't give you rate up :(

Comment: Glad to be of help. You can still mark the answer correct.